# How to display multilevel one to many relationship tree

Tags: php, html, mysql, parent-child, multi-level

How to loop all records and display all the respective children using HTML `<ul></ul>`? I tried using PHP Do While but stuck at only 1 level.

**MySQL (select * from user)**

[image]

**Desired output**

**Tree View**

[image]

**List View**

[image]

Comment: `SELECT name FROM user WHERE Parent = 'jason'`

Comment: whats your desired output??

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I've updated the desired output

Comment: You would normally store the id of the parent. Otherwise, why bother with the id at all

Answer (score 1):

The easy was is to do that with the help of array. Hope it helps.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $key = $item['name']; // or $item['info_id']
    if (!isset($data[$key])) {
        $data[$key] = array();
    }

    $data[$key][] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Hi i've updated my questions, your answer still valid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$aResults; // it is your mysql result (array)

$resultSorted = array();
$resultSorted = recursiveList($aResults, '');

function recursiveList(&$aResults, $iKey)
{
    $aChilds = '<ul>';
    foreach ($aResults as $iLoopKey => $aResult) {
        if ($aResult['parent'] == $iKey) {
            unset($aResults[$iLoopKey]);
            $aChilds .= '<li>' . $aResult['name'] . '</li>';
            $aChilds .= recursiveList($aResults, $aResult['name']);
        }
    }
    return $aChilds . '</ul>';
}

// Output example
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultSorted);
```

As a result, I recived:

[image]

Also you'd better use 'parent_id' instead 'parent' in yours tables.